# Header Overlapping Content while Manipulating Existing PDF Using API IText 7 Java

Tags: java, itext7

In our application, we convert html content to pdf using IText 7 then we manipulate the  newly created pdf to add header on each page of it. On first page, header shows up properly but from second page onwards it overlaps on content.

```
protected void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfReader pf = null;
    PdfWriter pw = null;
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = null;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        pf = new PdfReader(src);
        pw = new PdfWriter(dest);
        pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pf, pw);
        doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);

        TableHeaderEventHandler handler = new TableHeaderEventHandler(doc);
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler);

        float topMargin = 20 + handler.getTableHeight();
        doc.setMargins(topMargin, 36, 36, 36);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        doc.close();
        pdfDoc.close();
        pw.close();
        pf.close();
    }
}

private static class TableHeaderEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    private Table table;
    private float tableHeight;
    private Document doc;

    public TableHeaderEventHandler(Document doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
        initTable();

        TableRenderer renderer = (TableRenderer) table.createRendererSubTree();
        renderer.setParent(new DocumentRenderer(doc));

        LayoutResult result = renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, PageSize.A4)));
        tableHeight = result.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event currentEvent) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) currentEvent;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
        PageSize pageSize = pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize();
        float coordX = pageSize.getX() + doc.getLeftMargin();
        float coordY = pageSize.getTop() - doc.getTopMargin();
        float width = pageSize.getWidth() - doc.getRightMargin() - doc.getLeftMargin();
        float height = getTableHeight();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(coordX, coordY, width, height);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(canvas, pdfDoc, rect).add(table);
        c.close();
        
    }
    
    public float getTableHeight() {
        return tableHeight;
    }

    private void initTable() {
        table = new Table(1);
        table.useAllAvailableWidth();
        table.addCell("Header row 1");
        table.addCell("Header row 2");
        table.addCell("Header row 3");
    }

}
```

I tried many examples hosted at IText knowledge base to avoid overlapping but in all the examples they are creating the PDF, but in my scenario the PDF is already created using IText 7's HTMLConverter.

Comment: Well, you have mentioned yourself that the examples for adding headers and footers don't match your use case. The mechanism you try to use, page events, also doesn't match;  neither does setting margins or using a `Document` to begin with. Simply iterate over the pages and make sure that already in the step before, the HTML to PDF conversion, that enough margin space is reserved for later.

Comment: @Arnold hi, have you tried mkl's suggestion?

Comment: yes, but I have not been able to achieve the desired results.

Comment: @mkl hi, would you be able to share code example for how to find page breaks in html content to insert margin/space.

Comment: Please show your code doing the HTML-to-PDF conversion. This is the code in which you have to make sure there is enough margin to add header or footer. Or alternatively, here you have to select a slightly smaller page size you can later extend to get the required space for headers and footers. (Alternatively it might be possible by setting HTML styles; I cannot help there, though, my HTML knowledge is from the end of the 1990s...)